# How to auto straighten / level multiple photo in Lightroom CC

Tags: lightroom, automation, rotation

Is there any way to automatically straighten many photos in Lightroom CC? I do not intend to rotate 90 ° but to level them in an equivalent way to how this key would do
[image]

I would select multiple photo and then use a shortcut, a macro, or
any other method to do this automatically.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try [Upright automatic perspective correction](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom-classic/help/upright-automatic-perspective-correction.html):

> The Upright feature provides four modes of automatic perspective correction...:
>
> **Auto**: Balanced level, aspect ratio, and perspective corrections.
> **Level**: Perspective corrections are weighted toward horizontal details.
> **Vertical**: Perspective corrections are weighted toward vertical details and level corrections.
> **Full**: Combination of full Level, Vertical, and Auto perspective corrections.

You can sync the **Upright Mode** (*not* the Upright Transforms) across photos, it will then correct each image based on the content of that specific image.

Best to read the above linked manual page to understand how this Upright functionality can be used.

Comment: I did some tests and maybe "Auto" Upright Mode seems to work as I want. I will do more test on more foto. So if this works, how I can apply to multiple photo?

Comment: Saaru, based on my tests this function is unreliable and may lead to unpredictable/odd results.

Comment: I did some tests and for my purpose "level" is the right choice. Now I must understand how to apply to multiple file

Comment: @user3442473, as I said: "Best to read the above linked manual page". There the text "Upright can be copied (Copy Settings) or synchronized (Sync Settings), for use on one or more photographs..." describes how you can apply this to multiple files.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke tanx for your suggestion: For my case "level" mode and copy/paste developement settings works fine!

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of such method (to straighten more than one photo) in Lightroom. And the reason is sample, most of the LR functions are about to apply settings to bunch of photos. And copy process use same settings. But for straighten every picture is different and it not make much sense to apply the same amount. As you can see the only option is to replicate the same angle.
[image]

Comment: In fact I do not want / can apply the same rotation for each photo: I want him to perform the calculation on each photo as he would if I manually click on the "auto" button on each photo

Comment: @user3442473, you can't. The only thing you can is to apply same angle.

Comment: There is something like Photoshop actions, or macros that I can record and apply in which I tell Lightroom that "for each photo it has to go to the development TAB, press the crop key and then the auto key ...."

Comment: @user3442473, there is not option in LR.